# how to access phpmyadmin and type username and password?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Up until now I can't figure out why is phpmyadmin inaccessible when I put a password on the root user. 
But I've seen someone accessing phpmyadmin and inputting a username and password. How do I do that, so that I can access phpmyadmin even when I put a password to the root user. Because maybe by default the login form is inaccessible. Do I have to write my own php code to have that kind of login form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at phpmyadmin [documentation](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#config) there is some options about authentication.

quote from the relevant part of the documentation

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']
>   string
>   ['HTTP'|'http'|'cookie'|'config'|'signon']
>   Whether config or cookie or HTTP or
>   signon authentication should be used
>   for this server. 'config'
>   authentication ($auth_type = 'config')
>   is the plain old way: username and
>   password are stored in config.inc.php.
>   'cookie' authentication mode
>   ($auth_type = 'cookie') as introduced
>   in 2.2.3 allows you to log in as any
>   valid MySQL user with the help of
>   cookies. Username and password are
>   stored in cookies during the session
>   and password is deleted when it ends.
>   This can also allow you to log in in
>   arbitrary server if
>   $cfg['AllowArbitraryServer'] enabled.
>   'HTTP' authentication (was called
>   'advanced' in previous versions and
>   can be written also as 'http')
>   ($auth_type = 'HTTP') as introduced in
>   1.3.0 allows you to log in as any valid MySQL user via HTTP-Auth.
>   'signon' authentication mode
>   ($auth_type = 'signon') as introduced
>   in 2.10.0 allows you to log in from
>   prepared PHP session data. This is
>   useful for implementing single signon
>   from another application. Sample way
>   how to seed session is in signon
>   example: scripts/signon.php. You need
>   to configure session name and signon
>   URL to use this authentication method.
>   Please see the install section on
>   "Using authentication modes" for more
>   information.

I think you want to use the 'http' one.

Comment: so what's the summary of how to put authentication in php. It's really a lot. And I'm not good at it.